# How can I encrypt realm database data without deleting actual data?

Tags: java, android, encryption, realm

I am trying to encrypt my Realm database without deleting my actual data in my app.

I know how to generate a key and encrypt data in a silly way using the next code:

```
private Realm realm;
byte[] key = new byte[64];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);

RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = 
realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.
Builder().
encryptionKey(key).
build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

But for this sense I am modifying my Realm Configuration the previos data should be erased or it will cause an error.

This is my actual Realm Configuration:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.
                Builder().
                deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().
                build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Is there any way how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/encryptionExample

Comment: Worst case-  create a new db withthe new configuration, and read data from the old db into the new one, then delete the old.  I expect there's a better answer, but this would work.